# Salesforce SOQL, Get login history from login ID

Tags: authentication, salesforce, apex, soql

I have the following code

```
Id loginId = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('LoginHistoryId');
LoginHistory logHistory = [SELECT AuthenticationServiceId FROM LoginHistory WHERE Id=loginId];
System.assert(false, logHistory.AuthenticationServiceId);
```

Basically what I am trying to do is get the Id of Authentication Service through which I logged in. But I get an error saying

> Unexpected Token 'loginHistory'

If I try the following

```
LoginHistory loginHistory = [select AuthenticationServiceId from LoginHistory where Userid = :system.userInfo.getUserId() order by LoginTime desc limit 1];
```

it works. But I dont want it to be based on LoginTime.

Please tell me if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the manage [users permission assigned](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm)?

I was able to query this object without issue

The key part is this

> **Special Access Rules**
>   With one exception, only users with Manage Users permissions can access this object. The exception is that, in API version 37.0 and later, **all users can retrieve their own login history records**.